# The Simply Connected Manifold for $SU(3)$

Tags: differential-geometry, group-theory, topology

$U(1)$ is the 1-sphere (S^1);

$SU(2)$ is the 3-sphere (S^3);

$SU(3)$ is _______________ (fill in the blank).

What simply connected manifold is $SU(3)$ (isomorphic to)?

Comment: One assumes you have appreciated [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#The_group_SU(3))? This question resolutely belongs to the [math.se].

Comment: [For instance](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2701669/362193).

Comment: Unfortunately the simplest description for the manifold corresponding to $SU(3)$ is just "$SU(3)$", by a long shot. It ain't as simple as a sphere!

Comment: Thanks Cosmas and knzhou. That is interesting. I wonder why it was not just made S^7 (I presume it's related to (has something to do with) gravity)...Nevertheless, SU(3) is the stability group of a fixed imaginary octonion direction, and thus in this way perhaps can be related to a (as a) partial structure of S^7.Not resolutely mathematics as to be distinguished from physical reality and thus theoretical physics.